# Best Linq2Sql equivalent of IsNull(Max(id))

Tags: .net, sql, linq-to-sql

I'm looking to convert the following SQL into Linq2SQL.

```
select isnull(max(Id),0) from tbl
```

Even though I have Id defined as `Int NOT NULL`

I wish to be able to have a defult value of 0, even when there are no rows in the table.

The best readable approach I've been able to come up with is

```
var maxId = dc.tbl.Select(row => row.Id)
                  .ToArray().Union(Enumerable.Range(0, 1)).Max();
```

But this approach requires bringing down all the data, a more performant but less readable version is

```
var maxId = dc.tbl.Select(row => row.Id)
                  .OrderByDescending(ii => ii).FirstOrDefault();
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use something like the following.

```
context.Table.Max(row => (Int32?)row.Id) ?? 0
```

And by the way, I think your second suggestion is much more clear about the purpose than the first one.

**UPDATE**

I just tested the query with LINQPad. Should LINQPad cause the query to work while it does not in code, your second suggestion is probably the best solution.

```
context.Table
   .Select(row => row.Id)
   .OrderByDescending(id => id)
   .FirstOrDefault()
```

The drawback is that the default value is fixed at zero. This can be changed with the following query.

```
context.Table
   .Select(row => (Int32?)row.Id)
   .OrderByDescending(id => id)
   .FirstOrDefault() ?? 0
```

And just to note, the following does not work, because `LastOrDefault()` is not supported by LINQ to SQL.

```
context.Table
   .Select(row => row.Id)
   .OrderBy(id => id)
   .LastOrDefault()
```

Comment: That is, in the case where there are now rows

Comment: I checked it with LINQPad and it worked. It throws without the cast to nullable int.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
var maxId = dc.tbl.Any() ? dc.tbl.Max(e => e.Id) : 0;
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341264/linq-max-or-default), you may also do something like this:

```
var maxId = (from e in dc.tbl
            select (int?)e.Id).Max() ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
from t in tbl
select new {
  ID = ((System.Int32?)t.ID ?? (System.Int32?)0)
}
```