# LINQ Max() with Nulls

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that contains a bunch of Points (with an X and Y component).

I want to get the Max X for all points in the list, like this:

```
double max = pointList.Max(p=> p.X);
```

The problem is when I have a null in the list instead of a point.  What would be the best way to get around this issue?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Well, you could just filter them out:

```
pointList.Where(p => p != null).Max(p => p.X)
```

On the other hand, if you want `null`s to be treated as though they were points having X-coordinate `0` (or similar), you could do:

```
pointList.Max(p => p == null ? 0 : p.X)
```

Do note that both techniques will throw if the sequence is empty. One workaround for this (if desirable) would be:

```
pointList.DefaultIfEmpty().Max(p => p == null ? 0 : p.X)
```

Comment: I would not recommend using the `DefaultIfEmpty`. Please look at my answer as to why:

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18428483/575471)

Comment: @Nikkelmann I believe this is a LINQ query of in-memory entities, without a connection to any database.

Comment: @RamonSnir if that is the case then either is fine :)
But now ppl know not to use it for LinqToSql.

Comment: Or rather: Linq to Entities.

Comment: He could also use a nullable type, `pointList.Max(p => p == null ? (double?)null : p.X)` if he wanted. Note that with nullable types `Max` will not throw, not even with an empty sequence.

Answer (score 30):

If you want to provide a default value for X of a null point:

```
pointList.Max(p => p == null ? 0 : p.X)
```

Or to provide a default for an empty list:

```
int max = points.Where(p => p != null)
                .Select(p => p.X)
                .DefaultIfEmpty()
                .Max();
```

Comment: Interesting approach, I like it better than mine because it avoids the conditional and the `DefaultIfEmpty` is applied on the *result* type.

Answer (score 14):

I would not recommend using the `DefaultIfEmpty` in this case, since it produces a rather large SQL compared to other alternatives.

Please look at this example:

We have a list of modules for a page and want to get the maximum value of the column "Sort". If the list has no records, then null is returned. `DefaultIfEmpty` checks for null and returns the default value of the column data type when the column is null.

```
var max = db.PageModules.Where(t => t.PageId == id).Select(t => t.Sort).DefaultIfEmpty().Max();
```

This produces the following SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    MAX([Join1].[A1]) AS [A1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        CASE WHEN ([Project1].[C1] IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE [Project1].[Sort] END AS [A1]
        FROM   ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
            [Extent1].[Sort] AS [Sort], 
            cast(1 as tinyint) AS [C1]
            FROM [dbo].[PageModules] AS [Extent1]
            WHERE [Extent1].[PageId] = @p__linq__0 ) AS [Project1] ON 1 = 1
    )  AS [Join1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=11
go
```

If we instead cast the column to a nullable and let `Convert.ToInt32()` handle the null as so:

```
var max = Convert.ToInt32(db.PageModules.Where(t => t.PageId == id).Max(t => (int?)t.Sort));
```

Then we get the following SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    MAX([Extent1].[Sort]) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[PageModules] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[PageId] = @p__linq__0
)  AS [GroupBy1]',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=11
go
```

I can really recommend using ExpressProfiler for checking the SQL that gets executed:
http://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/

The last Linq expression can also be written as:

```
var max = Convert.ToInt32(db.PageModules.Where(t => t.PageId == id).Select(t => (int?)t.Sort).Max());
```

and will produce the same SQL but I like the more concise `.Max(t => (int?)t.Sort)`.

Comment: The problem with any ORM or tool that generates SQL for you is they make it so easy to shoot yourself in the foot. All you deal with is code and almost no one looks at the generated SQL. Problem with these mechanical translations is that they produce "One size fits all" code and sometimes, it is way bigger than what you may need. Thanks for highlighting that in this post. Bottom line, always check your generated queries! +1!!

Comment: +1 for always check your generated queries!  You can write bad SQL (so we profile it) but somehow the ORM always gets the blame when we don't profile (or even look at) the SQL it generates!

Comment: I'm trying to use this method, but I have a different query syntax so I can't seem to get the lamda expression in the select to work.  I am using `Convert.ToInt32( (from x in table join y in table 2 on x.ID equals y.ID where y.ProjectID == ProjectID select x.ObservationNum).Max());` Is there a way to do the joins with your syntax, or to modify my method to get to the nullable int cast?

Comment: @paul-gibson From the top of my head, try ".Max(t => (int?)t.Sort)".

Comment: Doh . . . and it's right there in your answer . .  . thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

Place a nullable cast INSIDE the expression to ensure that a blank list will cast as a null.  You can then add defaults.

```
double max = pointList.Max(p=>(double?)p.X) ?? 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
double max = pointList.Where(p=>p != null).Max(p=>p.X)
```

Should work.

Answer (score 1):

checking for null didn't work for me.  I used DefaultIfEmpty()

```
   int max_sequence = _dbContext.myTable
                .Where(e=>e.field1==param.field1
                && e.fieldDate==param.fieldDate
                )
                .Select(e => e.Sequence)
                .DefaultIfEmpty()
                .Max();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting to nullable

```
double max = (double?)pointList.Max(p => p.X);
```

more:
[Max or Default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341264/linq-max-or-default)

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply:

```
double? maxOrNull  = pointList.
    .Where(p => p != null)
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.x)
        .FirstOrDefault();
double max = 0;
if (maxOrNull.HasValue) max = maxOrNull.Value;
```

This will work with in memory lists and Linq2Sql, and probably efficiently also.

Answer (score 0):

Nullable column with max is as follow

```
var maximum = objectEntity.where(entity => entity.property != null).max(entity => entity.property.HasValue);
```

Above statement return maximum number of entity property