# How to create a non-nullable CRM basic type like int or double?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

When we create a new field in Microsoft Dynamics CRM, it will create it in the database as `NULL` allowed. How can you create a field in CRM that is `NON-NULL` in the backing database, like they do use for some of their own fields?

Selecting the Mandatory flag doesn't make it NON-NULL.

Reason for asking: when programming against CRM using LINQ, many queries become relatively difficult when you have to take care of nullables, and some even become impossible, like aggregate queries (try `Max()`, it will give a `InvalidCastException` when the underlying db type is nullable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though not exactly what you're asking for, you can achieve a similar effect via the API. Write a plugin against the `Create` and `Update` in the pre-validation stage (to catch the `null` value *before* the database transaction). If the non-nullable attribute is ever null, throw an exception, which will cancel the transaction altogether.

If you register the plugin *after* records have already been created, then you'd just have to make sure to populate those pre-existing records with values.

```
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

    if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
    {
        var target = ((Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]);
        if (target.LogicalName == Appointment.EntityLogicalName)
        {
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
            var entity = target.ToEntity<Xrm.Appointment>();

            if (entity.Description == null && entity.Attributes.Contains("description"))
            {
                throw new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.SaveChangesException("Fill in the field, buddy.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just realized this code is targeting a CRM 2011 instance, but I believe it should be portable to CRM 4.

Comment: This is certainly something to look for, however, I don't think it will make the auto-creation of the C# abstraction layer create non-nullable types, because the underlying type in the database is still nullable.

Comment: @Abel: Ah, I see - I think in that case, I partly misunderstood your question. In CRM 2011, `Max()` isn't even supported (but using fetchXml gets you the desired results while ignoring nulls).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say that there is simply no supported way of doing this ("supported" == "present in the SDK").

You can't even do anything at the SQL level without a lot of terrible hacking about (to remove the attribute and its dependencies, recreate it to disallow NULL then plumb it back in), which may not even work anyway.

I think the correct way to go is to overcome your LINQ issues. [Is this not a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047721/linq-max-with-nulls)?

Comment: For some reason, all those solutions still throw the same error. So, the problem is partially in the LINQ to CRM (FetchXML) translation, or v.v. Since I haven't managed to debug that part, I hoped I could fix it at the root.

Comment: Btw, you say "present in the SDK". Does that imply that it isn't possible to do from the CRM front-end either?

Comment: Correct - no way in the front end. Your only entry point in when you create the attribute and nothing there drives the NULLABLE property.