# LINQ Max on nullable datatypes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I have an entity as follows.

**SchoolDetails**

```
ID Name Rank  School
1  A           Lawrence
2  B      1    Lawrence
3  C      2    Lawrence
```

I need to fetch the details of student in a particular school(Lawrence) who has highest rank. In this example ID 2 is the desired output.

My linq query is:

```
var result = SchoolDetails.Where(x=>x.School == "Lawrence").Max(y=>y.Rank).SingleOrDefault();
```

I get a compliation message saying that "int? doesnt contain a definition for SingleOrDefault"

I cannot change the datatype of **Rank** column to make it non nullable since it is a production code.
So, given this situation how can I fetch a record with highest rank?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047721/linq-max-with-nulls

Comment: you don't need `SingleOrDefault` after using `Max` max returns the max `int?` and not a `List`

Comment: filter the  `null` value before the `.Max`

Comment: @MohammadAli : I need to fetch the entire object .

Comment: @user1907849 you can do order by Rank descending and get first element

Comment: @user1907849 then you need to get first the Max value of Rank and use it as comparison in your filter. You can write the filter directly into the SingleOrDefault method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below

```
var result = SchoolDetails.Where(x=>x.School == "Lawrence").OrderByDescending(x => x.Rank).FirstOrDefault();
```