# Filter List<Point> as per given Condition using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

One **Generic list** that contain **Points** say =>`List<Point>`

Now I need to filter **points** and store it in another `List<Point>` as per below condition and Using **LINQ**.

•   At **given Y** value of **Point**

•   Find Points with **Maximum X** values and **Minimum X** values.

**NOTE:**

Actually friends, I am looking for the LINQ query which performs above operation in just single query if possible.

Otherwise any best solution for above operation using **LINQ**,

**EDIT:-**
see my code here but i am looking for sort solution.....

```
               int givenY = 147;

                List<Point> listOfPointLocal = (from point in listOfPointMain
                        where point.Y == givenY
                        select point).ToList();

                var minX = listOfPointLocal.Min(p => p.X);
                var maxX = listOfPointLocal.Max(p => p.X);

                List<Point> listOfFilterdPoint = (from p in listOfPointLocal
                                         where p.X <= minX || p.X >= maxX
                                         select p).ToList();
```

Thanks…..

Comment: What code do you have so far? Can you post that please?

Comment: @Caspar, actually i have long way..first find points with given y,,, then fire query on it and find Points with MinimumX value and MaximumX value,,,,actually i am looking for way which perform above operation in single LINQ query.....thanks....

Comment: have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341264/linq-max-or-default

Comment: But what are your thoughts on this? It looks like you are searching for a ready-made solution without even getting your own head around it.

Comment: @Aryan SuryaWansi SO is NOT a mechanical Turk. The community is eager to help people with specific problems where the OP is willing to show its improvements. not wait and sit, please rephrase your question with appropriate code.

Comment: @Aryan, -1 for no evidence of attempting to solve the problem.

Comment: @All, hello friends see my edited question what i have till do.......but what i looking for is any sort solution...i felt like that my code is not proper there should be some proper or sort way for that.....is there any then please tell me..........Thanks.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little help from an extra class you can pass the list only once.

```
public class MaxMin
{
    public int max { get; set; }
    public int min { get; set; }
}
```

And then

```
var points = new List<Point>() 
                {
                    new Point(10, 10), 
                    new Point(15, 10), 
                    new Point(20, 10), 
                    new Point(42, 42), 
                    new Point(47, 11) 
                };

var maxmin = new MaxMin() { max = int.MinValue, min = int.MaxValue};
maxmin = points.Where(p => p.Y == 10).
                    Aggregate(maxmin, (acc, next) =>
                    {
                        if (next.X > acc.max) acc.max = next.X;
                        if (next.X < acc.min) acc.min = next.X;
                        return acc;
                    });
```

Answer (score 2):

to keep it a bit readable:

```
 var points = new List<Point>()
                    {
                        new Point(10, 10), 
                        new Point(15, 10), 
                        new Point(20, 10), 
                        new Point(42, 42), 
                        new Point(47, 11) 
                    };

var maxes = new {
    minX  = (from p in points orderby p.X select p).First(),  // with lowest x
    maxX  = (from p in points orderby p.X select p).Last(), // with highest x
    minY  = (from p in points orderby p.Y select p).First(), //  with lowest y
    maxY  = (from p in points orderby p.Y select p).Last() // with highest y
};
```

Comment: Then you would loose all information on that point's ranking in the other list.

Answer (score 1):

Although it does not give you min and max X in single query, following code may be useful to you.

```
        List<Point> list = new List<Point>();
        list.Add(new Point(10, 10));
        list.Add(new Point(15, 10));
        list.Add(new Point(20, 10));
        list.Add(new Point(25, 15));
        list.Add(new Point(30, 15));

        var minX = (from p in list
                    where (p.Y.Equals(10))
                    select p.X).Min();

        var maxX = (from p in list
                    where (p.Y.Equals(10))
                    select p.X).Max();
        Console.WriteLine(minX.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(maxX.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return the one result set, but it is still iterating the list twice, there is no way you can do it without that though AFAIK.

```
list.Select(a => new 
 { 
 Max = list.Where(max => max.Y == ???).Max(max => max.X), 
 Min = list.Where(min => min.Y == ???).Min(min => min.X)
 });
```