# Blackjack game, 'Sequence contains no elements'

Tags: c#, invalidoperationexception, blackjack

I created a Blackjack game for coding school and I'm modifying it to display other aspects of the game, like what card value total the dealer had and what value total I had at the end of the game.  It all works well until the Dealer Busted and I'm getting this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements'

I've googled and searched Stackoverflow, but I didn't understand any of the responses.  Here's my github code for it.
https://github.com/CrystalReimche/TwentyOneGame

In the TwentyOneGame.cs, line 143 is where where I'm trying to get it to display.

```
            foreach (KeyValuePair<Player, int> entry in Bets)
            {
                Players.Where(x => x.Name == entry.Key.Name).First().Balance += (entry.Value * 2);
                Console.WriteLine($"{entry.Key.Name} won {entry.Value} and now has a balance of {entry.Key.Balance}!");
                Console.WriteLine($"Dealer had {TwentyOneRules.DealerCardValue(Dealer.Hand)} and {entry.Key.Name} had {TwentyOneRules.PlayerCardValue(entry.Key.Hand)}");
            }
```

In the TwentyOneRules.cs holds the methods for it.

```
  public static Dictionary<Face, int> _cardValues = new Dictionary<Face, int>()
    {
        [Face.Two] = 2,
        [Face.Three] = 3,
        [Face.Four] = 4,
        [Face.Five] = 5,
        [Face.Six] = 6,
        [Face.Seven] = 7,
        [Face.Eight] = 8,
        [Face.Nine] = 9,
        [Face.Ten] = 10,
        [Face.Jack] = 10,
        [Face.Queen] = 10,
        [Face.King] = 10,
        [Face.Ace] = 1
    };

    public static int[] GetAllPossibleHandValues(List<Card> Hand)
    {
        int aceCount = Hand.Count(x => x.Face == Face.Ace); // Find out how many Ace's there are
        int[] result = new int[aceCount + 1]; // Plus 1 means if there's 2 Aces, there's 3 possible results ((1,1)||(1,11)||(11,11))
        int value = Hand.Sum(x => _cardValues[x.Face]); // Value is the lowest possible value with all Ace's == 1
        result[0] = value;
        if (result.Length == 1) return result;
        for (int i = 1; i < result.Length; i++)
        {
            value += (i * 10);
            result[i] = value;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static bool CheckForBlackJack(List<Card> Hand)
    {
        int[] possibleValues = GetAllPossibleHandValues(Hand);
        int value = possibleValues.Max();
        if (value == 2) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public static bool IsBusted(List<Card> Hand)
    {
        int value = GetAllPossibleHandValues(Hand).Min();
        if (value > 21) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public static bool ShouldDealerStay(List<Card> Hand)
    {
        int[] possibleHandvalues = GetAllPossibleHandValues(Hand);
        foreach (int value in possibleHandvalues)
        {
            if (value > 16 && value < 22)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static bool? CompareHands(List<Card> PlayerHand, List<Card> DealerHand)
    {
        int[] playerResults = GetAllPossibleHandValues(PlayerHand);
        int[] dealerResults = GetAllPossibleHandValues(DealerHand);

        int playerScore = playerResults.Where(x => x < 22).Max(); // Filter the values that's < 22 and bring me the max of the values
        int dealerScore = dealerResults.Where(x => x < 22).Max();

        if (playerScore > dealerScore) return true;
        else if (playerScore < dealerScore) return false;
        else return null; // this is a tie
    }

    public static int PlayerCardValue(List<Card> PlayerHand)
    {
        int[] playerResults = GetAllPossibleHandValues(PlayerHand);
        int playerScore = playerResults.Where(x => x < 50).Max();
        return playerScore;
    }

    public static int DealerCardValue(List<Card> DealerHand)
    {
        int[] dealerResults = GetAllPossibleHandValues(DealerHand);
        int dealerScore = dealerResults.Where(x => x < 22).Max();
        return dealerScore; 
    }
```

I'm thinking it has something to do with the Dictionary, since the methods work on other parts of the game that do not use the Dictionary.  For example, if I busted, it would display my card value total and the dealer card value total.

```
if (busted)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{player.Name} Busted!  You lose your bet of {Bets[player]}.  Your balance is now {player.Balance}");
                    Console.WriteLine($"Dealer had {TwentyOneRules.DealerCardValue(Dealer.Hand)} and {player.Name} had {TwentyOneRules.PlayerCardValue(player.Hand)}");

                }
```

I just don't have a good grasp on how to use the Dictionary properly yet.

Comment: First: you need to post a [mcve]. That means all relevant code must be **here**, not on GitHub. Second, you need to learn to debug your code, step through it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're invoking `Max()` (in either `DealerCardValue` or `PlayerCardValue`) on a sequence which contains no elements, as the `Where()` return value is an empty sequence, therefore there's no max value. This is written in the `Max()` function's [documentation in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335614(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_1).

Add `DefaultIfEmpty()` before `Max()` in `DealerCardValue` and `PlayerCardValue` to prevent `InvalidOperationException` from being thrown, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11884286/2928233), like so:

```
public static int DealerCardValue(List<Card> DealerHand)
{
    int[] dealerResults = GetAllPossibleHandValues(DealerHand);
    int dealerScore = dealerResults.Where(x => x < 22).DefaultIfEmpty().Max();
    return dealerScore;
}
```