# compare none value by linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an integer column(not null) in a sql server 2008 database/table, I want to retrieve it.

```
  // go to the table and get the largest number, if none exists, use 0.
        int iNumber = iContext.DetailsRecords.Max(x => x.Number); // from entity
```

But at the very beginning, the table is empty. I want to set is as 0.
How to change the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341264/linq-max-or-default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DefaultIfEmpty` for this.  If the sequence is empty it will return the provided item as the only item in the sequence, if not it will return the original sequence.

```
IEnumerable<int> numbers = new int [] { };

numbers.DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max();
```

Comment: +1, but I suspect this needs to be `iContext.DetailsRecords.Select(x => x.Number).DefaultIfEmpty(0).Max();`

Comment: @ReedCopsey Yep, but I didn't think it was too much of a leap for him to get there from what I provided.  Not all code answers need to be copy/paste/done to answer the question.

Comment: Well, I just thought I'd point it out since it actually requires another conceptual addition (the mapping operation via select) in addition to the original + your edit.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to check if the DetailsRecords is null, but rather handle if the source sequence is empty, then use this answer (I adjusted it a bit differently for your LINQ usage):

[Max or Default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/341264/linq-max-or-default)

---

`int iNumber = iContext.DetailsRecords.Select(x => (int?)x.Number).Max() ?? 0;`

- [`Enumerable.Max Method (IEnumerable<Int32>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292667.aspx): InvalidOperationException - 
  source contains no elements.
- [`Enumerable.Max Method (IEnumerable<Nullable<Int32>>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302925.aspx): If the source sequence is empty or contains only values that are null, this function returns null.

Comment: @Servy: Wrong. `Max(IEnumerable<int>)` of an empty sequence throws an exception. `Max(IEnumerable<Nullable<int>>)` of an empty sequence returns null. The casting is a valid solution (duplicate answer that has been accepted).

Answer (score 2):

try this:
 `int iNumber = iContext.DetailsRecords==null? iContext.DetailsRecords.Max(x => x.Number) : 0;`
or
`int iNumber = iContext.DetailsRecords.Any()? iContext.DetailsRecords.Max(x => x.Number) : 0;` if table is not null and contains 0 records.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what he's asking for, but I gave you a +1 in case it is. Though, I have a feeling it's that the DetailsRecords contains no elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Any` function to see if there are any records:

```
int iNumber = iContext.DetailsRecords.Any() 
              ? iContext.DetailsRecords.Max(x => x.Number) 
              : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this already has an accepted answer, but another good way would just be FirstOrDefault().

```
int iNumber = iContext.DetailsRecords.OrderByDescending(x => x.Number).FirstOrDefault();
```

I use this way often and also can let you setup a new object if the result was null.

```
 MyObject m = mySearch.GetItems.Where(a => a.id == id).FirstOrDefault() ?? new MyObject();
```

Comment: This will throw an exception when it reaches the `Max(...)` method.

Comment: Was showing example of how to use FirstOrDefault... Fixed code to reflect OrderByDescending so it'd work in this case.

Comment: Using the OrderByDescending with FirstOrDefault is an interesting take on this... The more answers, the merrier :)