# C# Linq, Find highest number from list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have below list, how do i find the highest or max number.

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
numbers.Add(2);
numbers.Add(5);
numbers.Add(7);
numbers.Add(10);
```

Please help!

Comment: oo ooo I know, pick me.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341264/linq-max-or-default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need to use Max method of list.

i.e :

```
var result = numbers.Max();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347632(v=vs.95).aspx):-

```
int highestNum = numbers.Max();
```