# Nhibernate Queryover, how to access nested proeprty

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

this is my model

```
public class A{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public ICollection<B> bs {get; set;}
}

public class B{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public ICollection<C> cs {get; set;}
}

public class C{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}
```

now i want to get Max(Id) of C class of a B object of an A object:

```
public int GetMaxId(int idA, int idB)
```

i try some diffente way:

```
var max= _session.QueryOver<A>().Select(a => a.Bs)
.Where(a => a.Id == idA).SingleOrDefault<ICollection<B>>()
.Where(b => b.Id == idB).FirstOrDefault<B>().Cs.Max(c => c.Id);
```

and

```
var max = _session.QueryOver<A>().Where(a => a.Id == idA).Select(a => a.Bs.Where(b => b.Id == idB)).Future<B>().Max(c => c.Id);
```

but nothing works

any way to do this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all be aware that `SingleOrDefault` and `FirstOrDefault` end your query. All that comes after will be processed in memory, not on the database! Besides that, you have a chance of a `NullReferenceException` after these methods.

To use nested properties in the `QueryOver` API you need to use aliases. As shown [here](http://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.html) under heading 'Aliases'.

But the simplest way in my opinion is to use LINQ instead:

```
_session.Query<A>()
    .Where(a => a.Id == idA)
    .SelectMany(a => a.Bs)
    .Where(b => b.Id == idB)
    .SelectMany(b => b.Cs)
    .Max(c => (int?)c.Id) // the cast makes sure you don't get a null reference (tnx to gt.guybrush)
```

Comment: In my LINQ example there is no chance of a null. Or do you mean a different query?

Comment: some problem in my unit test sorry, iam trying it :D

Comment: with no row in a,b and c table i get this error: System.Argument.NullException: value cannot be null. parameter name: item

Comment: An `ArgumentNullException` looks like it is executing in memory. Are you sure the exception is thrown from the query? Can you post a stacktrace?

Comment: solved in this way: .Max(c => (int?) c.Id) found on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/341264/max-or-default. if you edit your answer i will mark it as accepted